# Problem while installing MiKTeX 5.1 in Windows

Tags: miktex

I have been a user of MiKTeX (mostly using LyX to typeset my documents with the help of MiKTeX). Till now, I was using MiKTeX version 4.2 to do my work, and I decided to update it to the newest version of MiKTeX available (version 5.1). After uninstalling the previous version, I downloaded the files to my local machine and proceeded with the installation. However, just before the installation was supposed to start, I get this error:

```
Usage: setupwiz [OPTIONS]
Options: 
--allow-unattended-reboot
--auto-install=yes
--auto-install=no
--auto-install=ask
--common-config=DIR
--common-data=DIR
--common-install=DIR
--common-roots=DIRS
--download-only
--dry-run
--help
--install-from-local-repository
--local-package-repository= DIR
--no-additional-roots
--no-registry
--package-set=SET
--paper-size=A4
--paper-size= Letter
--portable[=DIR]
--private
--program-folder=NAME
--remote-package-repository=URL
--shared
--unattended
--user-config=DIR
--user-data=DIR
--user-install=DIR
--user-roots=DIRS 
setupwiz reads its arguments from setupwiz.opt, if such a file exists. See the MiKTeX Manual for more information.
```

Now, after this, there's only one 'OK' button, which closes the dialogue box. Nothing happens after that. I looked up the MiKTeX Manual as mentioned in the error message, but couldn't understand the error. I am further attaching the screenshot of the error dialogue box for additional information.
[image]

I will be very grateful if someone pointed out what is the matter with this installation.

P.S.: As MiKTeX is a very essential tool for my workflow, I reinstalled version 4.2 on my computer but didn't come across any such issues this time.

Edit (15-10-2022 10:15AM IST): I have tried every single of the mentioned probable methods but to no avail and the problem still persists.

Comment: where did you get these versions numbers? The current miktex has version `22.7`.  If you want to use the setup wizard to install you will have to use the command line and give it at least one option or as the message says write first an option file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I got these numbers from the installer that I downloaded from their website. I use the net installer for them. And I haven't used the command line to install MiKTeX up until now, so I don't know how to do it. Can you please show me how I can do that?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and also how to write an option file and use it.

Comment: why don't you use the basic installer if you don't know how to use the command line?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I need to have the complete tex distribution (as required by my instructor)...

Comment: sure, but after you installed the basic version you can install the rest of the packages with the miktex console. Simply select all missing packages and then click on the + for installation.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Typically the basic installer has the version in the name.

Comment: @DeBARtha From the version-number you provided I guess you use the MikTeX Net Installer. A small manual of the MiKTeX Net Installer can be found here: [https://docs.miktex.org/manual/setupwiz.html](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/setupwiz.html). You can provide command-line-options. Probably some of them are mandatory, i.e., must be provided? The last time I installed MiKTeX, in a first step I had everything downloaded to a local repository, and in a second step I installed from the local repository. Probably your instructor can provide a local repository from which instructed ones can install?

Comment: @DeBARtha I just found the question [Installation of MiKTeX for all users under Windows 10 – how to do it?](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/discussions/1104) on GitHub. The questioner seems to have encountered the same problem and found out that it was due to some malware-protection-software blocking proper installation.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I did precisely as you did last time, like downloading everything to a local repository and then installing them from that. But that's when I got this issue as I mentioned...

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution - right click the install file and run as admin should resolve your issues. Changing the install directory might also solve it.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, but only if I wanted to install to all users. So, try to install only for you, I didn't have any problem with that. But, if you really want to install to all users, try to run the program as administrator, that solved the problem for me.